# Proxy class C# how to make a variable of a call

Tags: c#, proxy

I got a class that handles the proxys for a project i bought. And i am looking for learning while doing some modifications to this project.

My question is how can i get a variabel from a void call? I supose the call Proxy.NewProxy(); is the one that grabs the new proxy from my list. But what i want to do is to make a variable of the proxy it got so i can list it in a logfile for example.

My class looks like this

```
class Proxy
{
    private static List<string> proxies = new List<string>();
    private static int proxyIndex = 0;

    public static WebProxy GetProxy()
    {
        string[] proxy = proxies[proxyIndex].Split(':');
        WebProxy wp = new WebProxy(proxy[0], Convert.ToInt32(proxy[1]));
        return wp;
    }

    public static void NewProxy()
    {
        if (proxyIndex < proxies.Count - 1)
        {
            proxyIndex++;
        }
        else
        {
            proxyIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    public static void AddProxy(string proxy)
    {
        proxies.Add(proxy);
    }

    public static void ClearProxy()
    {
        proxies.Clear();
    }

    public static void RemoveProxy(string proxy)
    {
        proxies.RemoveAll(a => a == proxy);
    }

    public static List<string> ListProxy()
    {
        return proxies;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question seems unclear (to me).. Mind explaining a little bit more?

Comment: Any reason you can't make it a not-void call and return the proxy?

Comment: @eddie_cat: how would i do that?

Comment: Just change the return type on your method where you need to "make a variable" from `void` to `string`, then at the end of your method return the relevant proxy string.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an event to your class:

```
public class ProxyGivenEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public String ProxyName { get; private set; }
    public ProxyGivenEventArgs(String proxyName) 
    {
        this.ProxyName  = proxyName;
    }
}

public static class Proxy
{
    // ...

    public static event EventHandler<ProxyGivenEventArgs> ProxyGiven;
    private static void OnProxyGiven(String proxyName)
    {
        if (Proxy.ProxyGiven != null)
            Proxy.ProxyGiven(null, new ProxyGivenEventArgs(proxyName));
    } 


    public static WebProxy GetProxy()
    {
        string[] proxy = proxies[proxyIndex].Split(':');
        WebProxy wp = new WebProxy(proxy[0], Convert.ToInt32(proxy[1]));

        OnProxyGiven(proxy[0]);

        return wp;
    }
    // ...
}
```

and use it like:

```
Proxy.ProxyGiven += (sender, args) =>
    {
         Logger.Log("Proxy {0} is given.", args.ProxyName);
    };
```

**P.S.:** You can tailor `ProxyGivenEventArgs` to include more info that will suit your needs.

For example if you need the instance of the instantiated proxy, then you can:

```
public class ProxyGivenEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public WebProxy ProxyInstance { get; private set; }
    public ProxyGivenEventArgs(WebProxy proxy) 
    {
        this.ProxyInstance = proxy;
    }
}

//...
private static void OnProxyGiven(WebProxy proxy)
{
    if (Proxy.ProxyGiven != null)
        Proxy.ProxyGiven(null, new ProxyGivenEventArgs(proxy));
} 

public static WebProxy GetProxy()
{
    string[] proxy = proxies[proxyIndex].Split(':');
    WebProxy wp = new WebProxy(proxy[0], Convert.ToInt32(proxy[1]));

    OnProxyGiven(wp);

    return wp;
}
```

and use it like:

```
Proxy.ProxyGiven += (sender, args) =>
    {
         Logger.Log("Proxy {0} is given.", args.ProxyInstance.ToString());
    };
```

**P.S.1:** If you aren't familiar with event model you may want to read [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I have been trying now for about 15h to read up on this. Somehow i cant really figure it out. I Took your code and put it in my class for proxys execpt the last group of code. But it throws errors.

First the first part it gives those kind of errors `Error 40 Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct`

and then a few of those errors `The name 'Proxy' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: Now it looks better, but it gives this error. `Method must have a return.` On the ` private static OnProxyGiven(String proxyName)
    {
        if (Proxy.ProxyGiven != null)
            Proxy.ProxyGiven(null, new ProxyGivenEventArgs(proxyName));
    } `

Comment: It directly points my mistake - in a rush I've forgot to write the return type of the method. The issue is already fixed in the answer, or you can just put `void` before `OnProxyGiven` - http://www.completecsharptutorial.com/basic/declaring-method.php

Comment: Yeah i was thinking about adding void i read somethings about it that it cant be emtey or similar. But did not want to mess it up. I will try it. You are so helpful!!

Comment: Seems to be correct now, but how would i convert the answer to a string or var? So i can set a variable to the current proxy in use.